# EOL while scanning string literal [in python sockets]

Tags: python, file, sockets, eol

I'm a newbie, and this is my first question on stackoverflow, so with that said, here's my question

> CLIENT CODE

```
import socket

cs = socket.socket()
ADDR = ('192.168.29.139',9999)
cs.connect(ADDR)

l = int(cs.recv(2048).decode())
data = cs.recv(l).decode()

data = eval(data)
cont = data["file"]["cont"]

f = open(data['file']['name'] + data['file']['ext'], "wb")
f.write(cont)
f.close()
```

> SERVER CODE

```
## SERVER SIDE


import socket

ss = socket.socket()
ADDR = ('192.168.29.139',9999)
ss.bind(ADDR)
ss.listen()

conn, addr = ss.accept()

msg = input("Enter message: ")
filepath = input("Enter filepath: ")
fileName = input("Enter filename : ")
fileExt = input("Enter fileExt:" )

f = open(filepath,"rb")
r = f.read()
f.close()
fileDict = {"name": fileName, "ext": fileExt, "cont": r}

msg_dict = {"msg":msg, "file": fileDict}
msg_dict = str(msg_dict).encode()

conn.send(str(len(msg_dict)).encode())
conn.send(msg_dict)
```

This method works totally fine when I transfer files within the same computer (even bigger files, like several GBs, in this test I was using the windows 7 test video, that was about 25MB) but when i use it on LAN to transfer the same file, between two computers within the same network it shows an error

right during this statement

```
data = eval(data)
```

the error was, after printing so many lines of characters like \xo... and empty lines

```
EOL while scanning string literal         ^
```

using pickle also gave error

Thank you for reading... Please HELP!

Comment: The parameter to `.recv()` is merely a maximum number of bytes to return - it will return whatever amount of data, up to that length, is currently available in network buffers.   So, you will generally need to call this in a loop until the entire data has been received.  (Note that your scheme of sending the length ahead of the data, so that this is even possible, doesn't quite work as written - the first `.recv()` is likely to return both the length, and some number of bytes from the actual data.  The length either needs to be of fixed size, or be followed by a terminator character.)

Comment: Thanks for your time @jasonharper, as you said I tried to make the message length same by padding the size equal to the header length, but nothing really changed, it works absolutely fine within one system (both server and client on same machine) but shows the same error across different machines in the LAN, thanks again for your help...